# How to prevent my background cover-image from cutting off when resizing (responsive)?

Tags: html, css

Creating a little interactive "game" for my schoolproject. The background image is an image of an office. It will have some stuff in that image that are clickable. for example, there is a computer standing somewhere, so I can click on that part of the screen and it does something.

I currently have set the background on the page, and fits the screen nicely after settings it to `cover` and aligning it `center`, issue is only that after resizing it for a small amount the left and right-size start to cut off. I need to make the site responsive for *some* smaller screens.

How can I avoid the image from cutting off, and just have it perfectly resize? adding `max-width/height` doesn't seem to work, because it will turn the page blank.

**HTML**

```
<div id="pagina2">
        <div id="pagina2Background">

            <a class="computer">
                <div class="computerHover">
                 </div>
            </a>

            <a class="bril">
                <div class="brilHover"></div>
            </a>

            <a class="bord">
                <div class="bordHover"></div>
            </a>

        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#pagina2 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%; 
}

#pagina2Background {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: url(../img/bureau.png);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Comment: From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) _Cover scales the image as large as possible without stretching the image. If the proportions of the image differ from the element, it is cropped either vertically or horizontally so that no empty space remains._ So i think you have to provide a different image for the mobile version of your size. If i understand the problem

Comment: Between the image width, its aspect ratio and the viewport width, something has to give. You image will either need to scale down or be cropped in order to fit on narrow screens. You've already figured out how to crop the image. Are you open to having it scale down? Also note that `background-attachment: fixed;` is ignored on iOS devices.

Comment: @volt yes I am open to having it scaled down.

The image will have something like a folder in the bottom-right of the screen, for instance. I will not be scaling-down to phone-size  or very small browser sizes, but it should be able to scale a little bit without cutting of the side, as described (in this case the folder will be cut-off from the image because the image is NOT scaling, but cropping as you mention)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the padding bottom (or top) by percentage trick to keep a constant aspect ratio. For example, if your image has size: width/height = 4/3, you can use padding-bottom is 75%. See the code below:

```
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 0;
  background-image: url('https://api.time.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/CatFilterReaction.jpg?w=600&quality=85');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  padding-bottom: 40%;
}
```